# When using the Sensu Handler for Elasticsearch, the logs are overwritten

Tags: handler, sensu

I have found a sensu handler on GitHub for shipping data to elasticsearch. It can be seen here https://github.com/m4ce/sensu-handlers-elasticsearch. I have configured this handler to send the keepalive events to Elasticsearch. When a critical event is generated, the log appears in Elasticsearch. However, when this event is resolved, the critical log is overwritten and replaced with the resolved log .I need to track both the critical and resolved logs so I can't have any logs being overwritten. Has anyone had the same problem, or does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Thanks,

AM

Answer (score 0):

The URI that the Sensu handler is POSTing to is:

`<elasticsearch_url>/<index>/<type>/<document_id>`

(you can see this on line 53 of the handler where the URI is built)

Where:

- `<elasticsearch_url>` is the `--url` parameter.
- `<index>` is the `--index` parameter.
- `<type>` is the `--type` parameter.
- `<document_id>` is the `id` field of the *Sensu event*.

There are two things to note about why this is happening the way you described:

1. A Sensu event, regardless of the `status` of the event, will always have the same ID.
2. In Elasticsearch, POSTing a document will overwrite an existing document with the same ID (`_id` field in Elasticsearch).

It seems like you're looking for a unique Elasticsearch document *per Sensu occurrence*, which would just be a matter of modifying the Sensu handler to write to a URL that has a truly unique `<document_id>` instead of one unique to the Sensu event. Elasticsearch will handle generating unique document IDs automatically, if you let it. That means you should be able to resolve this fairly easily, by modifying line 53 of the handler from:

`uri = URI("#{config[:url]}/#{index}/#{config[:type]}/#{@event['id']}")`

to:

`uri = URI("#{config[:url]}/#{index}/#{config[:type]}")`